# AutoMapper: User lowerCase value from member with same name

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper in my projects and I have 2 classes with same member names. I want to have them mapped but with different case: if upper, I want the destination object to have only lower cases.

I have this mapping

```
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {                   

                cfg.CreateMap<CompanyFolder, CompanyFolderEntity>()                        
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyId.ToLowerInvariant()))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ApplicationId,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ApplicationId.ToLowerInvariant()));
            }
        );
    }
```

And then I have unit tests that fail:

```
[Fact]
public void CompanyFolderMapping_ShouldBe_Valid()
{
    var companyFolder1 = new CompanyFolder()
    {
        ApplicationId = "APPLICATION_ID_1",
        CompanyId = "COMPANY_ID_1"
    };

    var companyFolderInfoEntity1 = Mapper.Map<CompanyFolderEntity>(companyFolder1);
    Assert.NotNull(companyFolderInfoEntity1);
    Assert.Equal(companyFolderInfoEntity1.ApplicationId, companyFolder1.ApplicationId.ToLowerInvariant());
    Assert.Equal(companyFolderInfoEntity1.CompanyId, companyFolder1.CompanyId.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

I do not understand why. I assume, can fix it using a Resolver, but why doesn't it work like this?

Comment: It works for me. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work, this is a "textbook example" of a custom mapping. Btw: I must highly recommend [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) nuget pckg, as assertion lib, instead of the default one

Comment: I have extracted the code in a sample app and tried it again. 
The thing is that for the classes I want to map I have another property 

public string FolderPath { get; set; }

and if I comment this property works fine; if I keep it, the mappings does not work anymore.

Comment: It seems it was related to a constructor that I have with parametes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. This are the classes that I have:

```
 public class CompanyFolderEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public CompanyFolderEntity(string companyId, string applicationId, string folderPath)
        {
            ApplicationId = applicationId;
            CompanyId = companyId;
            FolderPath = folderPath;
        }

        public CompanyFolderEntity()
        {

        }    

        public string FolderPath { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }    

        public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
public class CompanyFolderInfo
{
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

}
```

When I comment the first constructor and keep only the default one, it works fine. 
If I keep the constructors and comment the FolderPath member, it works fine.

As the code is above, it does not work.